# place selected text element into textbox, or submit selected words without a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to allow users to select given words from a word bank and place those into a text box. Once the user submits the input, I will create a script to verify the correct order of the words.

What I'm focused on now is how to select words from the word bank and place them as text (with spaces between each word) into the text box.

How can this be done? When the user clicks the word, just the Chinese word is placed, not the English.

---

**Edit:** The words don't necessarily need to be in a text box. I just want the user to be able to select words from the word bank, hit submit, and then allow the words in that order to be parsed. I figured the way to submit a string of words was thru a text box though.

---

[image]

HTML:

```
Create sentence:

<input type="text" id="test"  value="" />
<br/>
<button onclick="submitMe()" id="testButton" >Submit Response </button>
<br/>

<div class="wordBank_Headings">Word Bank:
    <span class="wordBank_Words"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var words = {
    "task1" :
    {
        'Ni'    : 'you',
        'Wo'    : 'I',
        'Hao'   : 'good',
        'Shi'   : 'am'  
    }
}

function bank() {
    $(".wordBank_Words").empty();
    for (obj in words) {
        for (key in words[obj]) {
            $(".wordBank_Words").append("<li><b>" + key + "</b>: " + words[obj][key] + "</li>");
        }
    }
}

function submitMe() {
//will eventually verify input from textbox
    var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: Can you put  "onClick" code of words ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an attribute to the li.  Then you can pull that off in the click event

```
function bank() {
        $(".wordBank_Words").empty();
        for (obj in words) {
            for (key in words[obj]) {
                $(".wordBank_Words").append("<li class='bank-word' data-display-word='" + key + "' ><b>" + key + "</b>: " + words[obj][key] + "</li>");
            }
        }
    }

    bank();

    $(".bank-word").click(function (event) {

        $('#test').val($('#test').val() + " " + $(this).attr('data-display-word'));
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Comment: Very nice. This works. thank you. Do I necessarily need to use a text box to submit? And what exactly is `data-display-word` in the context of a html element? I understand the li class, but not exactly what the other attribute is... I wasn't aware you could simply add your own attributes

Comment: Nogusta, once they select a word, how would I then remove it from the word bank? I tried `$(".wordBank_Words").hide($(this).attr('word'));` but that removes all of the words, and the whole section

Comment: They allow you to have your own custom attributes with valid HTML http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: I'll modify the answer to include the hiding

Comment: Okay, lastly. Two more things: `1)` If I delete the word from the text box (ie... user made a mistake), how can I add it back again to the word bank? The user should be able to delete any word in any order (ie: they delete Hao, the second word) and that word should reappear... and `2)` Why is it that all you need to do is `$(this).hide();`? Why doesn't my method of `$(".wordBank_Words").hide($(this).attr('word'));` work?

Comment: Also, what is `this`? Is `this` referring to the thing that's passed into the click function? If so, what is the thing that's passed in? If `$(this).attr('word')` is the word I click, then I know that `this` isn't the word itself... if that's the case, why does `$(this).hide();` remove the word you just clicked?

Comment: in regards to "this".  I found http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html is a better description then i could give in 500 chars

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44663/discussion-between-nogusta-and-growler)

Comment: Nogusta, can you help me answer how to place a word back into the word bank after user has deleted it from text box. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965102/unhide-hidden-words-that-have-been-removed-from-text-box

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to associate each `<li>` element with its Chinese word.
You can, for example:

1. Extract it from the html of the `<li>` element (wouldn't recommend).
2. Use a custom attribute such as `data-chinese` with each of the `<li>` elements. Just define it when you create the element, and access it later using [`$.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
3. Use [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the Chinese word of each `<li>` element. As in 2, store this data when you create the element.

Number 3 would look like:

```
function bank() {
    $(".wordBank_Words").empty();
    for (obj in words) {
        for (key in words[obj]) {
            $("<li><b>" + key + "</b>: " + words[obj][key] + "</li>")
                // append the new <li> element:
                .appendTo(".wordBank_Words")
                // store the chinese word in the element's data:
                .data('chinese', words[obj][key])
                // define the click event on the element:
                .on('click', function () {
                    var chinese = $(this).data('chinese');
                    var txt = $("#test").val() + " " + chinese;
                    // (you can conditionally add the space only if txt is not empty)
                    // update the text box:
                    $("#test").val(txt);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dn73c/1/) (click the words in the list).